# Secondary racking for store bought apple juice

Tags: cider, racking

New to home brewing, and have started out with some cider. I've started out with just store bought apple juice, 4l of which is now fermenting in a demijohn.

Is secondary racking required for this? My understanding is that secondary racking is to remove lees, but as I'm using store bought juice from a carton (no additives), shouldn't I be able to skip secondary racking? Or is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lees are not just the pectin precipitate from apple juice, or grape bits or beery crud from the biol, it is mostly your yeast cake.

I have brewed many things, wine, cider, beers, meads and sometimes I go to secondary, sometimes I lack a spare vessel, or I am lazy that day, or in a rush to make something as a test batch.

If you are careful when bottling then racking is not essential, but racking to a secondary if there is a lot of crap at the bottom of your demijohn can make the whole process easier.

To summarise, racking is not required but, it can make things easier and/or reduce sediment in bottles.